# jquery how do I find value of input within table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm an absolute novice at jquery.

Currently I have a table row:

```
<tr id="someID">
    <td class="pin"><input type="text">/td>
    <td><button class="addpin" type="button">ADD</button></td>
</tr>
```

I'm having a hard time getting the value of the text input. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addpin", function() {
    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").html();
    alert(mypin);
});
```

which alerts:

```
<input type="text">
```

but when I try:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addpin", function() {
    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").val();
    alert(mypin);
});
```

it's blank no matter what's in the input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings(".pin") ` get the td element with class name 'pin' not input element ,  `val()` is only work on form input

Comment: Use `$(this).closest("tr").find(".pin > input")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").children(0).val();
```

This will need to be adjusted if you put anything else into this cell.

Comment: You can also write $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").children("input").val();

Comment: Just needed the children index, makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addpin', function() {
    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").children(0).val();
    alert(mypin);
});
```

Fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/ztagdm5a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the value..

```
 var table = $("#table");
 var inputValue = [],

 table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');
            inputValue.push($tds.find('#InputID').val());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use text instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addpin", function() {
//Modified code:
var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").text();
alert(mypin);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the value

```
$(document).on('click', ".addpin", function() {

    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").html();
    alert(mypin); // Here mypin is a string("<input type='text'>") and not a form element

    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").val();
    alert(mypin);

   /*Here $(this).parent().siblings(".pin") is the td element and 
     val() of td will be blank as you are getting.*/


   /*This is what you are looking for.
     Find the input element inside the td and extract the value*/

    var mypin = $(this).parent().siblings(".pin").find("input").val();
    alert(mypin);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with siblings work great.
This is just an additional info.

I assume in this case, you have one text box which takes the pin name and click on "Add" button to add it to a list or something.

```
$(this).parent().children(0).val();
```

$(this).parent() --> Will go to the parent level from "Add" button block

children --> will be an array

children(0) --> the input element which is the first element